# Confusion regarding ASCII

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I understand that ASCII is a scheme of character encoding, where a Byte is assigned a certain decimal number, hexcode or a letter of our alphabet.

What I don't understand and couldn't find out via Google is how exactly the computer deals with ASCII behind the scenes. For instance when I write a text file with the text "hello world", what is the computer doing? Does it save the bytes in memory and where does the ASCII encoding come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost anything that computers store on disk, transfer over the network or keep in their memory is handled as 8-bit chunks of data, called bytes.

Those bytes are just numbers. Anything between 0 and 255 <sup>*</sup>.

So a 100 byte file is just 100 numbers one after each other.

A network message is similar: it's just a bunch of numbers one after the other.

(We tend to abstract over those and call them something like "streams", because at some level it often doesn't matter if you read from a file on disk or receive a network message, they are fundamentally just finite streams of bytes).

If you want to display a file from the disk as text, something needs to convert those numbers to something meaningful for humans. Because if I tell you that a file contains the bytes `68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 0a`, then chances are you don't really know what that means. (By the way, those are hex values which is already an interpretation, one could equivalently say that the file contains the decimal byte values 104, 101, 108, ...)

ASCII is a pattern of how to *interpret* those numbers. It tells you that 0x68 (decimal 104) represents the character `h`. And that 0x65 (decimal 101) represents `e`. And if you apply that mapping to those bytes you'll get `hello world`.

That decoding only has to happen when the computer wants to show the text to a user, because internally it doesn't *care* that 0x65 is `h`. So if the computer wants to display some text to you it looks up what letter 0x65 represents `h`, probably represented again via its Unicode codepoint which *happens to be* U+0065 and then it looks up how that character is represented in the font. The font then has a mapping of U+0065 to some instructions on how to draw the `h`.

And since we're talking about ASCII it should be mentioned that ASCII is not actually used an awful lot these days, mostly because it only supports a very limited set of characters (basically just barely enough to write English language text, and not even all of that). More commonly used encodings today are UTF-8 (which has the benefit of being ASCII compatible which means all valid ASCII text is also valid UTF-8 text, but not the other way around) and UTF-16. Other encodings that used to be popular, but are on the decline are the ISO-8859-* family (which are basically extended versions of ASCII, but still only support a small number of characters each).

<sup>* So technically even saying "those are numbers between 0 and 255" is already an interpretation. Technically they are 8 bits, each one of which can be off or on. Those can be interpreted as an unsigned number (0 to 255), a signed number (-128 to 127), a character (using something like the ASCII encoding) or potentially anything else you want. But the "unsigned number" interpretation is one of the most straightforward ones.</sup>

Comment: Just to understand better: "Those bytes are just numbers. Anything between 0 and 255." These are the numbers assigned within the ASCII Tables right?  And when does the computer translate the 8 bit chunk into a number like 101?

Comment: The mapping of those 8 bits to an (unsigned) number is simply interpreting them as a [binary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) in a specific order. Just as decimal (10 digits) and hexadecimal (16 digits) are number formats, so is binary (2 digits). So the binary 1101000 is the same as the hex 68 or the decimal 104, they are the same number.  This mapping is not itself defined by ASCII, that's considered a given. Also **technically** ASCII only needs 7 bits, but since computers work with 8-bit units now, everyone just assumes it uses 8 bits and the highest-value bit is 0.

Answer (score 2):

> For instance when I write a text file with the text "hello world", what is the computer doing?

When you hit those keys on your keyboard, a certain protocol between the keyboard and computer lets the computer know which keys were hit. The computer translates that into a character, like "h", based on what keyboard layout is currently selected. It may also cause your video game character to move sideways or whatever else, there's no direct connection between a key and what it causes to happen. But let's say you're in a text editor and your computer interpreted your hitting the "h" key as "inputting the letter *h*". It now turns that into some internal, in-memory character representation. Often in-memory representations will be UTF-16 encoded bytes, so the computer can represent any and all possible Unicode characters.

When you hit File → Save as..., you select to store the file in ASCII encoding. The text editor now goes through the UTF-16 bytes stored in memory and converts them all into equivalent ASCII bytes, according to a UTF-16/Unicode → ASCII encoding table. Those bytes are stored on disk.

When you open that file again, the text editor reads those bytes from disk, probably turns them into its internal UTF-16 representation, and stores them in memory so you can edit the file. At this point you can typically think about each character as a *character*; it doesn't matter what bytes it's encoded as, that is abstracted away. An "h" is just an "h" at this point.

Each in-memory character is mapped to a glyph in a font, typically by its Unicode code point, to be able to display a graphical representation of it on screen for you.